# Backbone.js Router history back to initial page

Tags: backbone.js

Okay I have googled and googled and can't find anything related to my actual problem.

Basically I have a simple router defined with a few routes all of which can be rendered directly by the server if called directly.

So the backbone history is called like this.

```
Backbone.history.start({
    'pushState': true,
    'silent': true
});
```

I then have simple a very simple navigate

```
this.navigate($(event.currentTarget).attr('href'), {
    'trigger': true
});
```

This all works correctly except for one flaw.

Lets say you start on the home page of the site which I do not have a backbone route defined for and then click a few links on the site that use the backbone router, you will get routed to the correct page and everything is fine, but then when you click the browser's back button to get back to the home page you end up seeing the contents of the first backbone route and not the actual homepage's contents.

So I am realizing that I need to store the initial page contents so that I can reinsert them into the page once I detect that I am back to the initial page that does not match a route in my Router, and then from there I need to reload in the stored version of my page.

So I would like to know if this sounds right, or if I am going down the wrong path, also does backbone offer anything to help with this scenario that I am just missing? And I can't be the only one who has tried to do this so how have others gotten around this issue?

(Initially I thought there was actually a problem with my code, and not actually this fundamental issue, so I still want to ask this question to figure out how others have accomplished this)

Comment: I'm dealing with this problem right now, curious if you came up with any solution. I'm thinking of creating a special "refresh" route that will server render them in those cases.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach to me. I will let you know if I come up with something better. I currently reworked it so that pages that do not have a loadable backbone page, will not use backbone in the first place. It is less then ideal, so I am still looking for a better solution but at least I can move on and come back to it later.

Comment: Yeah I ended up client-side rendering the page, kind of a bummer and a weird issue. I guess it probably has something to do with the `root` of the Router. Maybe I need multiple routers per `root` (in my case most of the app is server-side rendered, but a few flows were client-side and needed back-button / URL support)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route for the homepage. What happens is that each time you follow a link, the current URL is pushed on `pushState`'s stack, and each time you hit the back button the previous URL gets popped and Backbone tries to follow its route. However, when you pop the homepage URL, there's no route that it matches so Backbone doesn't actually do anything, leaving the content as whatever it was the last time a route really did match.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in my question but I have a bunch of these pages that do not have routes, or more importantly I do not have a simple method for pulling the content down for backbone to handle. So I am sure this works but would require me reworking the entire site instead of just making a quick / ajax loaded version of my search page.